# Float всегда целое

Tags: .net, winforms, c++

```
int x=5, y=5, z=4;
float r=(x*5+y*5+z*4)/(x+y+z);
MessageBox::Show(System::Convert::ToString(r));
```

Выводит всегда 4, без точки с запятой. Почему?

Comment: замените r=(x*5+y*5+z*4)/(x+y+z) на r=(x*5.0+y*5.0+z*4.0)/float(x+y+z)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас в выражении

```
 (x*5+y*5+z*4)/(x+y+z)
```

все аргументы целые, поэтому деление происходит целочисленное, и результат тоже целочисленный.
Чтобы получить float результат, надо хотя бы один из аргументов привести к float:

```
 float(x*5 + y*5 + z*4) / (x + y + z)
```

или неявно:

```
(5.0f * x + 5.0f * y + 4.0f * z) / (x + y + z)
```

Comment: обычно делитель делают нужного типа (x*5+y*5+z*4)/float(x+y+z)

Comment: IAZ: впервые слышу. А почему так?

Comment: можно хоть один член выражения сделать float, и все остальные будет преобразованы.